# nmap correct TCP traceroute

Tags: tcp, traceroute

[image]

Why is only hop 1 & 6 displayed?
Note: I can't use ICMP, due to firewall. The target is an educational website in the AWS cloud.

Comment: Please include text as text, not as image.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about networks you do not directly control are off-topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tracing the path of packets works by sending packets with different TTL and expecting routers on the way to discard packets if the TTL is exceeded and send a ICMP TTL exceeded back. The source IP of the ICMP TTL exceeded is the IP address of the router on the path.

While routers will discard packets if TTL is reached, they will not send a ICMP TTL exceeded back every time. And some systems will not send it back it at all. But if no ICMP TTL exceeded the IP address of the discarding router is kown, it is only known that the packet got somewhere discarded but not where. Therefore no information can be shown about these systems.

This is actually pretty normal, and happens no matter if nmap, tracepath, traceroute or similar tools get used.